# How can I align this table with another way?

Tags: tables, math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I tried to align this table. My code

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
1 & $=$ & 1 \\ 
$2 + 3 +4$ & $=$ & $1+8$ \\ 
$5+6+7+8+9$ & $=$ & $8+27$ \\ 
$10+11+12+13+14+15+16$ & $=$ & $27+64$ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I see the signs `=` are far from the left and the right. How can I align this table with another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the material should be in math mode, I suggest using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. If nothing else, it saves you from having to enter lots of `$` characters by hand.

Observe that the `array` has *only two* explicit columns. The middle column, with all the `=` symbols, is generated automatically and needn't be typed by you. The `@{{}={}}` in the array header instructs LaTeX to insert an `=` symbol between the first and second column, with spacing that's appropriate for an operator of type `mathrel`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[  % start display math mode
\begin{array}{c @{{}={}} c}
1 &  1 \\
2 + 3 +4  & 1+8 \\
5+6+7+8+9 & \phantom{0}8+27 \\
10+11+12+13+14+15+16  & 27+64
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up inquiry: If the two columns of the `array` environment should be right-aligned instead of centered, just change the column specifier from `c` (for "center") to `r` (for "right"):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} r}  % <-- note the "r" column specifiers
1 &  1 \\
2 + 3 +4  & 1+\phantom{0}8 \\
5+6+7+8+9 & 8+27 \\
10+11+12+13+14+15+16  & 27+64
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to keep the center alignment but shove the entire `array` to the right-hand edge of the text block, the following code will do what you want (the horizontal line is just there to illustrate the width of the text block):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\hspace{\fill} 
$ % use inline-math rather than display-math mode
\begin{array}{c @{{}={}} c@{}}
1 &  1 \\
2 + 3 +4  & 1+8 \\
5+6+7+8+9 & \phantom{0}8+27 \\
10+11+12+13+14+15+16  & 27+64
\end{array} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well remembered: `@{{}={}}` is nice!

Comment: @Mico How can I align `\[ 
\begin{array}{c @{{}={}} c}
1 &  1 \\
3+5  & 8 \\
7+9+11 & 27 \\
13+15+17+19  & 64\\
21+23+25+27+29&125
\end{array}
\]` to the right?

Comment: @minthao_2011 - Please clarify what you mean by "align ... to the right": Do you want to shove the entire array to the right, or should one or the other column (or both columns) be right-aligned?

Comment: @Mico Alingn to the right of the digits in unit.

Comment: @Mico I want to shove the entire array to the right.

Comment: @minthao_2011 - I posted an addendum with two extra solutions. Hope one of them is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Mico I am sory. Because I do not attention to your code. It's too easy:)